# Grid view at Ubuntu touch - How to use it?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt

In article about [content views](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps/global-patterns/content-views#grid-view) is a part about a Grid view. But I didn't found anywhere how to use it. Do you knew something about it? 
Tahnks for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is available in Qt Quick

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-gridview.html

Here is the link to the tutorial. Sorry, can't give more info in the answer but the tutorial is good.

Answer (score -2):

The link you posted links to a guideline on how to make an application with the Ubuntu design. There is an example, the photo viewer app, which uses the grid layout. But the Grid is not an app nor part of the Operating System.

Comment: So you sad that grid view is not in Ubuntu touch. So I can't use a grid layout in my Ubuntu touch app. Is that right? Thanks.